mathematics on monotonic e-greedy policy improvement

The picture is the shortcut from the Stanford CS234 RL course note. I have a question about the proof on the monotonic property of $\epsilon$-greedy policies. In the red underlined expression, if some $\tilde{a} \in A$ makes the value of the red underlined expression less than 0, then shouldn't
$$\frac{\pi_i(\tilde{a}|s)-\frac{\epsilon}{|A|}}{1-\epsilon} \max_{a'}Q^{\pi_i}(s, a') < \frac{\pi_i(\tilde{a}|s)-\frac{\epsilon}{|A|}}{1-\epsilon} Q^{\pi_i}(s, \tilde{a})$$ be true? Specifically, the inequality sign needs to be reversed -- it's no longer "greater than or equal to". Moreover, considering the scenario when $\epsilon$ tends to 1, which means we take uniformly random actions, why does the value function $V$ still have the monotonic improvement? Thanks.

The problem statement assumes that $\pi_i$ is $\epsilon$-greedy. By definition (see section 5.4 of Sutton & Barto), an action is chosen uniformly randomly with probability $\epsilon$ at each time step; otherwise, the greedy action is chosen. Since there are $|A|$ actions, each action $a \in A$ has a $\frac{\epsilon}{|A|}$ probability of being chosen randomly at each time step. Therefore, $\pi_i(a|s) \ge \frac{\epsilon}{|A|}$ for all $a \in A$, and the expression underlined in red can never be negative.
In the case that $\epsilon = 1$, both $\pi_i$ and $\pi_{i+1}$ will both choose actions uniformly randomly. Note that this "improvement" is still monotonic since $V^{\pi_i}=V^{\pi_{i+1}}$, and equality is allowed in the definition of (non-strict) monotonicity.
